# Is there any way to fit and apply deep learning algorithm on chemical smiles data in sequential model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have written a code for this where my input as an X

X : c1ccccc1 and Y value is water/methanol as classification category.

```
# multi-class classification with Keras
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("ADLV3_1.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,2:3]
Y = dataset[:,3:4]
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold)
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

Code running successfully but getting warning as

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py:235: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py:268: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

  FitFailedWarning)
Baseline: nan% (nan%)
```

Is there any solution to make the algorithm workable? I can't predict any values

Comment: Do any values of X contain characters?

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is or what your objective is.

Comment: It's a smiles in Value of X = C1CC(C2=C(C1)C(=CC=C2)O)O and the issue is it can't fit the model showing nan values.i can't predict values.

Comment: FitFailedWarning happens if the parameters are not in required format, sounds like you have `NAN` values. Handle missing values before fit method. Thanks!

Comment: i've checked there are not nan value still facing this issue

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/interpretable_ml_drug_discovery/blob/master/AMES_interpretability.ipynb) help to solve your issue. Thanks!